# Check in weirdness after merge

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Visual Studio 2010.

A few weeks ago we branched our project, and yesterday we merged them.  It all went well, and the newly merged project appears to have captured correctly the differential changes.

However, when I check an object out for edit, and then go to check it back in, I get a very long list of objects in the Check In dialog.

The newly checked out object is marked as **lock,edit** in the Change column.

However, every other object in the project ALSO appears in the list marked as **merge, lock**

I can't find out what this means, and I don't want to check them in, in case the previous merge operation is changed or undone.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It sounds like you didn't check your merge in...

Comment: stupid question, but after you did the merge and resolved any conflicts, did you check the merge in? It looks like the merge is still "pending" in your workspace.

Comment: Well, after the merge all the files in the solution were checked out, so I checked them all in.  Other developers can see the changes, but don't get the extensive list of pending checkins that I get.  Anyway, I'll take a copy of the code, and check it in and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to bite the bullet and check in the outstanding pending changes, having reviewed the difference between a selection of the pending changes and the known good versions, and finding no difference.  It all seemst to have gone through correctly so I'll mark this down to experience.